# Mixed Diagram (Line/Bar) with two y-Axis won't display data on 2nd Axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

as title states. I'm trying to create a diagram with chart.js-2. The diagram is supposed to show datapairs for humidity and temperature. On the X-Axis i display time. I have two Y-Axis - one for temperature and another for humidity. Even though the data appears in the Tooltip it is not illustrated.

The data is provided in this format:
Timestamp;Sensor_ID;Temperature;Humidity;
2019-06-29 11:13:56;1;24.60;51.80;

Here is a fiddle with a "working" example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/sHooP_/ky4nha7L/22/

```
data: {
        datasets: [{
        type: 'bar',
        yAxisID: 'Humidity',
        label: 'Humidity',
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
        data: objDataset_Humid_Filtered,
        borderColor: 'blue',
        borderWidth: 2,
        fill: true,
      }, {
        type: 'line',
        yAxisID: 'Temperature',
        label: 'Temperature',
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
        borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
        data: objDataset_Temp_Filtered,
        fill: false
      }]
    }´
```

Thanks for any any answers! I'm starting to get frustrated about this.

I'm also pretty sure my coding is not very clean (Beginner) so if you happen to have any tips feel free!

Best regards,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js lets you add a line to a bar chart, but not a bar to a line chart. So you need to set the *chart* type to bar, e.g.:

```
var config = {
  type: 'line', // <-- change to 'bar'!
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! That works with my fiddle. My real data contains way more data though. Could it be that it can't be displayed due to too many bar-datapoints? Is there a fix?

Comment: @sHooP You simply need to try it and see if there is a problem. It should work but might look bad and render slowly. You can read about [High Performance Line Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html?h=perfo) if you need further guidance.